# Since English is a stress-timed language, why have poets chosen to write in iambic pentameter?

Tags: stress, meter

Since English is a stress-timed language, why have poets chosen to write in iambic pentameter? Doesn't the language already have a natural rhythm without resorting to meter? And isn't that natural rhythm already quite close to iambic pentameter?

Comment: Could you give some examples? Not all of us are familiar with technical terms.

Comment: Maybe see the [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)#History) and [Dissent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)#Dissent) of metre.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Poets chose to write in Iambic pentameter because they wanted to. Why did they want to? Well, you need to ask a historian but I imagine the traditions derived from Latin and Greek were factors. Languages with word stress patterns do, of course, have their own rhythm, but it's inevitably irregular and in the mind of classically influenced poet an irregular and naturally occurring meter is probably insufficient. That's why they tend to work English's natural stress pattern into a precise meter, such as iambic.

Comment: That is a big question.  A book like Stephen Fry's https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ode-Less-Travelled-Unlocking-Within/dp/0099509342 may help. Superb explanation of metre.

Comment: The classical terms for quantitative (long-short) meter are 'translated' in discourse about English prosody into qualitative (stressed-unstressed) equivalents. English poetry is still measured, but the units run stress-to-stress. See [http://english.stackexchange.com/q/97500/24489]

Comment: @Sandwichmeister I think I'm asking whether the natural rhythm of English is really so different from iambic pentameter that a precise meter is called for. It seems that the definition of a stress-timed language is regular stress patterns, which already accomplishes what meter sets out to do. Although here's an interesting thought: perhaps meter serves not only to highlight regularities, but also to highlight irregularities? That is, accenting syllables which we wouldn't expect to accent.

Comment: The terms for poetic meter were designed and implemented for Greek and Latin poetry, which were similar in their poetry, basing it not on stress or timing, but on vowel length in morae. Modern English speakers can't tell Classical Latin poetry from prose by ear, and English poetry from Chaucer on wouldn't sound like poetry to Greek or Roman ears, either. So fussing about "iambic pentamer" is silly; there isn't anything special about it. And many poets don't use it all that much anyway. The real question is: what, if anything, is the natural rhythm of spoken English?

Comment: No offence, but this question seems to be more about your dismissive attitude towards Iambic pentameter than an actual question. Many English speaking poets evidently did feel there was something special about, which is why they worked so hard to fit the natural rhythm of English into it's meter. Many modern poets don't use it, well obviously, many modern poets don't even care about meter.

"what, if anything, is the natural rhythm of spoken English?"

This question doesn't really make sense, English doesn't have a strict meter, there are just natural linguistic patterns in stress.

Comment: @Sandwichmeister You misinterpreted my comments, then! I do not feel a dismissive attitude towards iambic pentameter. On the contrary, I enjoy a lot of poems and plays written in this meter. This enjoyment is what led me to reflect on the meter, and why some of the authors whom I admire choose to employ it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting! It's helpful to think of the historical context. I think I have read and overheard that iambic pentameter approximates the natural rhythm of conversational English. But this might not be true. Perhaps there are no 'natural rhythms' in the English language. Or maybe it depends on time and place.

Comment: @Sandwichmeister After re-reading my question, I don't see where you got that impression. The question is so concise (a mere three straightforward sentences) that I don't see where any attitude comes across.

Comment: The stress pattern of an English sentence, it's meter if you will, is defined by many factors. In regular speech important words tend to be stressed, unimportant words tend to be reduced as in "A cup of tea" o ~ o ~. In addition to these each word has its own stress pattern. The most common stress pattern being first syllable stress, but there also being plenty of example of 2nd and 3rd syllable stress. The rules are as follows: 1st syllable unless the 2nd syllable is a diphthong /oʊ/ /aɪ/ /eɪ/, or a long vowel /iː/ /juː/ or if the word ends in a consonant cluster.

Comment: @JohnLawler But the question you're asking isn't really about English. You're basically asking why many English speaking poets chose to fit English's natural time stressed rhythm to Iambic pentameter. The only answer is because they wanted to, why they wanted to might be better explained by a historian. The natural rhythm of a time stressed language will never as regular as a poetic meter, so no doubt they thought it more beautiful or perfect when the meter was exact. Why they often preferred Iambic is probably down to its historical significance. There's little else to be said.

Comment: @Sandwichmeister I think there's a lot to be said, such as why English poets chose iambic pentameter. But you seem to be arguing that it would be more appropriate to ask a historian, than the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. I disagree. I think this is an appropriate forum for my question, as it has precisely to do with English *usage*: why do poets use the language in this way?

Comment: @Sandwichmeister On a side note, I feel like this comment chain exemplifies a problem that I and others have on ELU. In addition to asking a question, we have to argue that the question is *worthy* of being answered. I feel like a young professor trying to argue with a journal that my essay is worthy of publication. I don't think that ELU should feel that way, but it often does.

Comment: First, is there any evidence that most English poets write in iambic pentameter? I haven't seen any. Second, is there any evidence that most English poets **strive to** write in iambic pentameter? Ditto. Third, is there any actual evidence about the normal rhythmic structure of normal **spoken** English? I haven't seen anything presented here about any of these topics. Hence this is all uninformed speculation.

Comment: @JohnLawler Blank verse was widespread during the 16th and 17th centuries, and it was even popular through the 19th century. There is plenty of evidence for that. Shakespeare, Milton, Keats, Shelley. It is definitely one of the most important poetical meters in our language, so I think it makes sense to wonder why.

Comment: "Blank verse" being the same as "iambic pentameter"? The claim that one or the other was "widespread" is not the same claim as the claim that "poets have chosen to write in iambic pentameter": How many poets  did so, and how much of their output was one or the other variety? If you have a case to make for the importance and salience of a particular meter, present it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Basically. Or unrhymed iambic pentameter, to be more precise.

Comment: I wasn't finished with writing my comment before I deleted it. Mostly due to typing on my cell phone, having no access to my computer at the moment. Let me try rephrasing: Asking a question on ELU is like walking into someone's home in the woods. They pull out a gun and ask you why you're trespassing.

Comment: @ktm5124 Everybody here has completely different educational and linguistic backgrounds; many if not most are non-native speakers. We get silly questions and silly answers of all varieties. That's why facts are important and handwaving is discouraged. I don't think it has to do with American rural stereotypes at all, if that's what you meant by _hillbilly_; it's more like walking into the market outside the Delhi train station.

Comment: It is the hostile attitude of some people towards questions, even interesting ones such as this one, that has given EL&U its terrible reputation on SE. I wish people were more welcoming, and I wish they just moved on if they didn't like the question for some reason. Unreasonable demands in comments are part of this bad attitude. I personally think it is a very interesting question.

Comment: You may be interested in the answer to this question: [What's the evidence for and against isochrony?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12089)

Comment: @sumelic That is very helpful. One line of thought, then, would be that there isn't enough isochrony in the English language for poets to rely on the natural rhythm; thus, a stricter meter is preferable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49202/discussion-on-question-by-ktm5124-since-english-is-a-stress-timed-language-why).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Note: It's actually a matter of some debate whether there really exist "syllable-timed" and "stress-timed" languages; but I think this question is answerable within its premise that there do, and that English is "stress-timed" — in fact, I think the answer is fairly similar *whether or not* that's the case — so I'll give it a shot.)

Unstressed syllables aren't silent; if the interval between two stresses is the same no matter how many unstressed syllables come between them, then stresses with more syllables between them will force those syllables to be said faster, which results in a faster rhythm.

So having roughly the same pattern of unstressed syllables throughout a sentence will result in a regular cadence:

> - Liz Anne drank mixed drinks. (five stressed syllables, ´´´´´)
> - Sally Mae had drunk a vodka tonic. (five trochees, ´˘´˘´˘´˘´˘)
> - Amanda Jean had drunk a rum and coke. (five iambs, ˘´˘´˘´˘´˘´)
> - Jessica Coleman was trying out something with grenadine. (five dactyls, ´˘˘´˘˘´˘˘´˘˘´˘˘)
> - Alexandra was trying out something with peppermint schnapps. (five anapests, ˘˘´˘˘´˘˘´˘˘´˘˘´)

(Incidentally, note that not all of the cadences work equally well; personally I think the iambs and anapests work best, though that's probably subjective.)

By contrast, a more haphazard arrangement of unstressed syllables will have no such cadence:

> - Liz Anne was drinking something with vodka. (´´˘´˘´˘˘´˘)
> - Jessica Coleman drank mixed drinks. (´˘˘´˘˘´´´)

Of course, a regular cadence is not absolutely *necessary* to poetry. And iambic pentameter is far from the only possible regular cadence in English. ([Common meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_metre), for example, uses alternating lines of four and three feet; and [limericks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_%28poetry%29) use anapests.) But it's a pleasant rhythm, and — as you imply — it falls within the normal range of natural English rhythms. (And of course, once a meter becomes common, it takes on a life of its own; later poets used it in part because they were in the same tradition of earlier poetry that had used it.)

Comment: Very good ruakh. both scholarly and clear, it got my upvote. However I found myself fitting "_Jess_ -I-ca _Cole_-man drank _mix_ -e-ed _dri_-i-inks into 3:4 waltz time without even thinking about it. I wonder if asking a question about the relationship between cadence, poetic metre and musical time signatures would be worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

There was a pseudonymous work in the 18th century purported to be written by Sheridan that claimed Shakespeare was not witing iambic pentameter but a hexameter line with pauses in a variety of places adding up to one foot.He also claimed that there were any number of other feet in Shakespeare lines thrown in, trochees, dactyls anapaets, molossus etc. He distinguished between arsis and thesis or weight and lightness and said that these did not correspond to stress. he analysed the interpretations of Garrick , kean, Bettereton to show that there were many ways of apportioning stress and pause in a hexameter line. He was attempting to discover a unique form of muscicality in English poetry not directly related to the Greek Iamb or 'limp'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).