# What is it called when a poetry stanza alternates between iambic tetrameter and triameter?

Tags: poetry, meter

What is it called when a poetry stanza alternates between iambic tetrameter and triameter?

1. If **I** shall **wan**der **in**to **hell**
2. And **die** up**on** its **coals**

So we have one line of iambic tetrameter and one line of iambic triameter. Is there a name for structures like this? Or is it just really iambic heptameter that has been divided between lines?

Comment: To my ear, I'm pausing at the end of line 2. If so, that rest is a tacet fourth iamb, so the tetrameter repeats.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I see. So you're saying it is simply two lines of tetrameter, with the last iamb of line two being left as a silent rest? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, to my ear: Mary had a little lamb, her fleece was white as snow. Mary had a little lamb, the doctor was surprised.

Comment: It’s probably ***wander***....

Comment: @FaerieFire BTW, would you mind sharing the source of your example lines? It looks like a rendering of part of Ps. 139; I'd like to read the rest of it.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97500/meter-in-clares-i-am/97677#97677

Comment: @YosefBaskin: tacet fourth iamb? That's ridiculous. A pause is not an iamb.

Comment: As mentioned in Nigel J's answer, the term for a line with three beats is *trimeter*, not *triameter*; it might be worth editing this if only to help when others search the same question in future.

Answer (score 11):

This is called 'Common Metre'if it is repeated once, that is to say if the lines are : 8,6,8,6.

> The Lord's my Shepherd, I'll not want.
> He makes me down to lie
> In pastures green : he leadeth me
> the quiet waters by.

[Psalm 23, the first stanza. The Scottish Psalter 1929.]

> Common metre or common measure [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_metre) —abbreviated as C. M. or CM—is a poetic metre consisting of four lines that **alternate between iambic tetrameter** (four metrical feet per line) **and iambic trimeter** (three metrical feet per line), with each foot consisting of an unstressed syllable followed by a stressed syllable. The metre is denoted by the syllable count of each line, i.e. 8.6.8.6, 86.86, or 86 86, depending on style, or by its shorthand abbreviation "CM".

[Wikipedia - Common Metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_metre)

---

Just out of interest, the other forms which are usually met with are short metre 6,6,8,6 :

> To thee I lift my soul :
> O Lord, I trust in thee:
> My God, let me not be asham'd,
> nor foes triumph o'er me.

[Psalm 25 first stanza, The Scottish Psalter 1929]

. . . . then double common metre (which simply doubles the lines to eight lines),  then long metre 8,8,8,8 then double long metre (doubling to eight lines).

Comment: This is related to your answer, @Nigel J, but not the question. How are you able to do single-spacing like that in your Psalm quote? Whenever I try to single-space in an answer with one hard return, the actual post doesn't end up with it down a line but on the same line. To avoid that, I have to do two hard returns, but that puts it two lines down, not one, so everything I write, like a poem, that requires a hard return at the end of a short line instead of wrapping around to the next line, like your second quote does, ends up double-spaced. I've tried everything...

Comment: ...to make something appear like your "The Lord's my Shepherd" line, but I can't. So if you could clue me in on how you did taht, I'd appreciate it, @Nigel J.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I didn't know how, but Andrew Leach has edited and I see from that edit that the way to do it is to do _two spaces_ at the end of the line, before hitting the return to go to the next line. Neat !

Comment: Thanks, @Nigel J. That is **extremely** helpful information!!!!

Comment: And thanks, @Andrew Leach, I wish I could give you an up-arrow on your edit, because in it, you've just taught me how to get past an issue that's been frustrating me **forever**. So, *thank you, thank you, thank you!!!*

Comment: The fun part is that you can sing anything in Common Meter to the tune of "Amazing Grace" (or any other song with common meter verses). My English teacher had us do this in class with a poem, I believe by Emily Dickinson.

Comment: Short Metre (S.M.) is 6.6.8.6, not 6.6.6.6.

Comment: @RosieF Yes indeed. Thank you. My bad. Edited to correctness.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Another way is to end the line with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

What @Nigel J said: *common meter.* I just wanted to add another example of common meter to try out something I just learned from @Andrew Leach's edit of @Nigel J's answer, how to single space:

**"Because I Could Not Stop For Death"**
**by Emily Dickinson**

Because I could not stop for Death –
He kindly stopped for me –
The Carriage held but just Ourselves –
And Immortality.

We slowly drove – He knew no haste
And I had put away
My labor and my leisure too,
For His Civility –

We passed the School, where Children strove
At Recess – in the Ring –
We passed the Fields of Gazing Grain –
We passed the Setting Sun –

Or rather – He passed Us –
The Dews drew quivering and Chill –
For only Gossamer, my Gown –
My Tippet – only Tulle –

We paused before a House that seemed
A Swelling of the Ground
The Roof was scarcely visible –
The Cornice – in the Ground –

Since then – 'tis Centuries – and yet
Feels shorter than the Day
I first surmised the Horses' Heads
Were toward Eternity –

Comment: It scans better as: "Because I could not stop for Death".

Comment: @GEdgar I'm straight putting the edit in because I've never seen it without.

Comment: Other famous examples include "Amazing Grace", "The Yellow Rose of Texas", and the *Gilligan's Island* theme song, with the consequence that any of these can be sung to the tune of any of the others. Personally I enjoy singing "Amazing Grace" to the tune of the *Gilligan's Island* theme song.

Comment: Notably one pair of lines have the 4/3 count reversed to 3/4, e.g.: *"Or rather – He passed Us –/The Dews drew quivering and Chill –"*  I think she did that in several of her poems.  @ruakh: Add "The Merry Old Land of Oz" to that list.